# Nested switchNavigator inside a component with React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Im stuck with a Nested Navigation System. I have a main navigator (switchNavigator) and one of its screens is a component witch inside has some views and inside of one of this views  I want to put another navigator (switchNavigator), but I get this error "`The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation v3 and v4 you must set up your app container directly.`". I really don't know if it's posible or a valid implementation.

This is my mainNavigator and two simple components, the second one is where I call the nested navigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createAppContainer,createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import NestedNav from './nestedNav';

const FirstView = props=>{
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>First view</Text>
    </View>
  )
  }
  const secondView = props=>{
  return(

    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>Second view</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <NestedNav></NestedNav>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>some other ui content</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    firstView:FirstView,
    secondView:secondView
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'secondView',
  }
);
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator)
```

And this is my NestedNavigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createAppContainer,createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

const NestedNav = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    firstView:SomeFirstViewInNestedNav,
    secondView:SomesecondViewInNestedNav
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'firstView',
  }
);
export default NestedNav
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I just had to create a static reference of the nested Navigation's Router in my nested navigator container component (in the example "secondView" component): 

`static router = NestedNav.router`

And set the navigation prop to the nested navigator:

 `<NestedNav navigation = {this.props.navigation}></NestedNav>`

This solution is in the Docs: [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/common-mistakes/#explicitly-rendering-more-than-one-navigator)

Answer (score 0):

as you rendered the nestedNavigator it should be in wrapped into a appContainer.

```
const NestedNav = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    firstView:SomeFirstViewInNestedNav,
    secondView:SomesecondViewInNestedNav
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'firstView',
  }
);


--> export default createAppContainer(NestedNav)
```

Comment: But when I try this I get this warning `You should only render one navigator explicitly in your app, and other navigators should be rendered by including them in that navigator. `

Comment: because navigator should be in a tree structure but in this case NestedNav is another tree root rendered within a component.